# How to create RelayCommand that has functionality that changes the Header value of the control?

Tags: wpf, command

RoutedUICommand has functionality that changes the Header value of the control.

For example, the code below would change the Header value of the MenuItem to the "Cut".

```
<MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Cut"/>
```

But if the RelayCommand is used instead of the "ApplicationCommands.Cut" then Header value of the MenuItem not changed.

```
public static class MenuActionCommands
{
    public static MainWindow parentWindow { get; set; }

    public static readonly RelayCommand NewProject = new RelayCommand(NewProjectExecute, NewProjectCanExecute);
}

<MenuItem Command="commands:MenuActionCommands.NewProject"/>
```

My goal is to combine RelayCommand functionality with RoutedUICommand functionality that changes UI Header value.

For example, I want to create the command below and to use it.

```
public class RelayUICommand : RelayCommand
{
    // include functionality that changes control Header value.
}
```

Could someone tell me what I should do to solve this problem?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Maybe official source code of RoutedUICommand(https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/system/windows/Input/Command/RoutedUICommand.cs) can help you... By the way, Is the usage of your RelayUICommand is like 'RoutedUICommand but Executes the Action I want' or 'RelayCommand but changes Header of element which it has binded to' ?

Comment: Thanks for comment. What I want is like the second opinion. In other words, I want 'RelayCommand but changes Header of element which it has binded to'.
I don't want Route functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MenuItem.Header` value is set automatically when the `MenuItem.Command` binds to a `RoutedUICommand` and the `RoutedUICommand.Text` property is set.

So you have to use a `RoutedUICommand` and set the `Text` property. Then delegate the call to your `RelayCommand` instance:

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
  public static RoutedUICommand NewProjectRoutedUICommand = new RoutedUICommand() { Text = "Create New Project" };    

  // Perhaps this command is exposed by a view model
  public static RelayCommand NewProjectRelayCommand = new RelayCommand(NewProjectExecute, NewProjectCanExecute);

  public MyUserControl()
  {
    this.CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(NewProjectCommand, ExecutedNewProjectRoutedUICommand, CanExecuteNewProjectRoutedUICommand));
  }

  private void ExecutedNewProjectRoutedUICommand(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    // Delegate to RelayCommand instance
    MyUserControl.NewProjectRelayCommand.Execute(e.Parameter);
  }

  private bool CanExecuteNewProjectRoutedUICommand(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    // Delegate to RelayCommand instance
    return MyUserControl.NewProjectRelayCommand.CanExecute(e.Parameter);
  }
}
```

**Usage**

```
<MenuItem Command="{x:Static MyUserControl.NewProjectRoutedUICommand" />
```

---

Alternatively add a `Text` property to your `RelayCommand` and bind it to the `MenuItem.Header` property:

```
public class RelayUICommand : RelayCommand
{ 
  public RelayUICommand(Action<object> executeDelegate, Func<object, bool> canExecuteDelegate, string description) : base(executeDelegate, canExecuteDelegate)
  {
    this.Text = description;
  }

  public RelayUICommand(Action<object> executeDelegate, Func<object, bool> canExecuteDelegate) => this(executeDelegate, canExecuteDelegate, string.Empty);

  public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

**Usage**

```
<MenuItem Command="{x:Static MenuActionCommands.NewProject}" 
          Header="{x:Static MenuActionCommands.NewProject.Text}" />
```

**Reusable version** (will set the `MenuItem.Header` automatically)

```
<!-- Use in conjunction with the RelayUICommand -->
<Style TargetType="MenuItem">
  <Setter Property="Header" 
          Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Command.Text} />
</Style>

<MenuItem Command="{x:Static MenuActionCommands.NewProject}" />
```

Comment: Hm... Could you show me an alternative example? I want to use like <MenuItem Command="commands:MenuActionCommands.NewProject"/>  in XAML. but the code above doesn't seem to be able to that because it has to define command in the UserControl.

Comment: Yes. This would require to add define a `RoutedUiCommand`. Since this command is `static` you can define it everywhere as long the definig type extends `DependencyObject`. But I can update my answer to show you the alternative solution.

Comment: I added another option. When using a `Style` you can "automate" the assignment of the `Header`.